# Custom href title in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I've got a glossary topic page that lists terms I want to define. Each term looks like this:

```
\anchor glossdefinedterm
<dl>
    <dt>defined term</dt>
    <dd>The defined term is a word in the glossary that we define. Lorem ipsum...</dd>
</dl>
```

Then, I @ref glossdefinedterm "the defined term" elsewhere. What I'd like to do is provide the definition text in such a way that it shows up as the "title" property of the  link in the generated HTML, thusly:

```
This is called a <a href="path/to/glossarytopic.html#glossdefinedterm" title="The defined term is a word
in the glossary that we define. Lorem ipsum...">defined term</a>.
```

This way, the user won't have to click the defined term to see the definition and can just mouse-hover instead.

How might I accomplish this?

Thanks much for suggestions! I'm a Doxygen newbie, so type slowly. :)

Comment: Maybe study the questions and answers her on stackoverflow regarding `xrefitem` might give you some ideas.

Comment: Yah, I've been studying them but haven't found success in what I need to accomplish.